# Soundpool not playing correctly

Tags: java, android, xml, soundpool

I'm creating a little game where I have audio samples from a drumkit set to play when image-buttons are touched.  Its working on one device but not two others I've tried it on.  Is there anything in my code that makes it inconsistent across Android devices? I cannot find any reason for this inconsistency... Any genius out there with a solution??

### Activity Code

```
public class GameMain extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_main);

    // Initialise SoundPool to play the drum sample sounds
    soundPoolDrums = new SoundPool (8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    // Create HashMap of sounds
    soundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  }

  // Constants and variables for storing sounds for drumkit
  public static final int HIHAT_SOUND_ID=0;
  public static final int RIDE_SOUND_ID=1;
  public static final int CYMBAL_SOUND_ID=2;
  public static final int BASS_SOUND_ID=3;
  public static final int SNARE_SOUND_ID=4;
  public static final int TOMTOMA_SOUND_ID=5;
  public static final int TOMTOMB_SOUND_ID=6;
  public static final int TOMTOMC_SOUND_ID=7;
  private SoundPool soundPoolDrums;
  private Map<Integer, Integer> soundMap;

  /*
   * The next section manages the playback of drum samples
   */

  // High-hat sample player
  public void HatOne (View view) {

      soundMap.put(HIHAT_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumhata, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(HIHAT_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Ride sample player
  public void HatTwo (View view) {

      soundMap.put(RIDE_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumhatc, 1));
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(RIDE_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
      }

  // Crash sample player
  public void Crash (View view) {

      soundMap.put(CYMBAL_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumcrash, 1));   
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(CYMBAL_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
      }

  // Bass sample player
  public void KickDrum (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(200);

      soundMap.put(BASS_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumkick, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(BASS_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Snare sample player
  public void SnareDrum (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(150);

      soundMap.put(SNARE_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumsnare, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(SNARE_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // High tom sample player
  public void TomOne (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(120);

      soundMap.put(TOMTOMA_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumtom1, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(TOMTOMA_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Mid tom sample player
  public void TomTwo (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(120);

      soundMap.put(TOMTOMB_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumtom2, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(TOMTOMB_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }

  // Low tom sample player
  public void TomThree (View view) {

      Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vib.vibrate(120);

      soundMap.put(TOMTOMC_SOUND_ID, soundPoolDrums.load(this, R.raw.drumtom3, 1)); 
      soundPoolDrums.play(soundMap.get(TOMTOMC_SOUND_ID), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
  }
  // End of sample players section

  // Handlers for Back buttons
  // If tactile back button is pressed then the user is returned to the home screen
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){

    soundPoolDrums.release();
    soundPoolDrums = null;

    // play back sound
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundbackbutton) ;
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    // short vibration
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(200);

    Intent s = new Intent (this, Main.class);
    startActivity(s);
  }

  // Handler for back button 
  public void BackButton (View view) {

    soundPoolDrums.release();
    soundPoolDrums = null;  

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundbackbutton) ;
    mMediaPlayer.start();

    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(200);

    Intent s = new Intent (this, Main.class);
    startActivity(s);   
  }

}
```

XML files

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fabricblacksmr">

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BackButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:onClick="BackButton"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonhome"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#00000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/gamemaintext" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="HatOne"
            android:src="@drawable/dhihats" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dride"
            android:onClick="HatTwo"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dcrash"
            android:onClick="Crash"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="KickDrum"
            android:src="@drawable/dbassdrum"
            android:background="#00000000" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"  
            android:src="@drawable/dsnare"
            android:onClick="SnareDrum"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dtom1"
            android:onClick="TomOne"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dtom2"
            android:onClick="TomTwo"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtongame8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dtom3"
            android:onClick="TomThree"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/filsdrum"/>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft ="120dp" 
        android:text="@string/copyright"/>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Did you do any investigation on your side on why "Its working on one device but not two others I've tried it on" ? Without investigation on your side its difficult if not impossible to figure out why its not working. Please do more research, is it that the soundpool request to start is being sent but its not be serviced? is it that it can't find the sound? Are you catching the exception and not doing anything? Do some research about the code you are writing before asking for help, as it stands right now its a little too hard to say. Also look at the logs from the framework, may have useful inf

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Some food for thought in your comments.  I was hoping for a solution like the SoundPool is set up wrong or that there is a line of code missing that will fix the flaw...